# ubuntu 12.10 dual boot with windows 8 on two hdds

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8

i am attempting to install ubuntu 12.10 on a machine in dual boot with windows 8. the machine has two hard disks - each about 2TB in size. i install windows 8 on /dev/sda and this works fine - windows 8 boots up and i can do everything on it ok.

then i put in the ubuntu 12.10 live cd and go to install ubuntu. i am presented with the following options for installing ubuntu:

[image: step 1]

and i choose `something else` then click continue. the following screen comes up:

[image: step 2]

when i click the dropdown box it shows me the following options:

```
/dev/mapper/isw_bjchifhafj_Volume0   Linux device-mapper (mirror) (2.0 TB)
/dev/mapper/isw_bjchifhafj_Volume0p1 Linux device-mapper (linear) (367.0 MB)
/dev/mapper/isw_bjchifhafj_Volume0p1 Windows 8 (loader)
/dev/sda
```

i select `/dev/mapper/isw_bjchifhafj_Volume0p1 Linux device-mapper (linear) (367.0 MB)` for the boot loader. i then highlight `/dev/mapper/isw_bjchifhafj_Volume0` in the list of devices and click `new partition table`. this automatically creates the free space shown highlighted in the above picture.

i then doubleclick on the free space and set the `type` to `primary` and `ext4`, set the size to 381MB, and set the mount point as `/`. it whinges about not having swap-space, but since i cannot figure out how to further partition the drive i just click `continue`.

it then starts installing linux and immediately dies. i can't remember what the error was but it just wiped my windows installation completely from the hard drive. what did i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should have selected the first option i.e. /dev/mapper/isw_bjchifhafj_Volume0   Linux device-mapper (mirror) (2.0 TB) which has the free space. but the option you selected had the Windows 8 partitions, So as far as I think your windows 8 is still there it is just that you need to install grub or configure it to show and load windows 8.

Let me know if you have any further queries...

Comment: thanks. i have installed ubuntu in a vm and i don't want to screw it up again, but i might try again in a year or so.