# What location to put bootloader, when running multiple drives and partition

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, system-installation, bootloader

I have Win8 on my desktop, where a 120G SSD is used to run windows and some select applications, while I have a 2TB HDD to provide basic file storage and where possible, install applications instead of on the SSD.

I want to install Ubuntu on a new partition of the HDD (I allocated 300GB, with 5GB swap file).

I've used a USB to install the OS, which seemed to have done the job. However, after prompting for a restart, I can no longer boot to ubuntu.

During instillation I was confused about where to install the "boot loader instillation". I ended up selecting "/dev/stb" because I figured I would be able to boot with BIOS by selecting the HDD drive as a priority over the SSD.

**The bootloader is a large part of where I think I went wrong.**

My partition system looked something like this:

```
/dev/sta  ...               //SSD ~120 GB
/dev/sta1 NTFS (350 MB)     //Win8System
/dev/sta2 NTFS (118 GB)     //Win8C-Drive

/dev/stb ...                //HDD ~2TB
/dev/stb1 NTFS (1563 GB)    //FileStorage
/dev/stb5 Free Space (300 GB)    //Space I want to use for Linux
```

(NOTE: Created two partitions from the 300GB, ~5GB and 295GB. stb5,stb6.)

It'd be great if I could get an explanation of **what drive you'd select for the boot loader and why, and what selections won't work with regards to the Boot Loader Instillation.** I think I understand what Grub is, but I have no idea on how to use it, or play around with it.

I seem to be able to get back into OS from my usb, however I believe it's just showing me a preview/trial of Ubuntu (ie, can't access any of the system NTFS drives). Note, if I try to install from the USB again, it will recognize that a version of Ubuntu 13.10 exists on the system.

Apologies in advance, have used windows all my life, don't really know to much about Linux at all. Did have a brief skim over some similar questions, didn't find anything too useful.
 - [Where to install bootloader when installing Ubuntu as secondary OS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219514/where-to-install-bootloader-when-installing-ubuntu-as-secondary-os)
 - [ubuntu 12.10 dual boot with windows 8 on two hdds](https://askubuntu.com/questions/243679/ubuntu-12-10-dual-boot-with-windows-8-on-two-hdds)
 - [Dual-boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu on two SSDs with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244703/dual-boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-on-two-ssds-with-uefi)

EDIT: Found Solution

Turns out, after I attempted to re-installing once more, that what was required was to create the root partition (~295GB) as a `primary` partition instead of the default selected `Logical`. It wouldn't recognize a logically formatted root partition.

All working now, I'm typing this from Ubuntu as we speak. (Yipeee!)

EDIT: Clarification

I still left the boot loader instillation specified to '/stb', and now I can use the BIOS to boot from the SSD or the HDD interchangeably. Very handy.

I still require an explanation as to why:

- Using a Logical partition would not be recognised the system's BIOS (I have an ASUS H-87 Pro Mobo).
- What would be different if I changed my boot loader instillation instead to '/sta'? Would I no longer directly boot into Windows, and instead use the Grub interface every time?
- Is there a preferred place to install the boot loader instillation? Clarifying that specifying volumes such as '/sta1' or '/stb5' would not allow you to load the OS?

Comment: I'm glad you've found a solution (as per your edit); however, for the benefit of others (or you) who ask questions in the future, be aware that this question is incomplete because it doesn't identify the boot mode (BIOS vs. EFI) for Windows or Linux. This detail is *critical* for answering the question. In fact, some people will make assumptions about this when answering, which can lead to a wild goose chase. See [this page](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/bootmode.html) for information on how to identify your boot mode.

Comment: Hi Rod, thank you for your feedback. I have identified the boot mode is definitely BIOS, looking from within Windows and Linux with advice from your link. Cheers.

Comment: Just wanted to clarify, BIOS does not recognize OS's installed on logical partitions? Was this my problem before?

Comment: In BIOS-mode booting, the BIOS loads the first sector of the disk and executes the code that it contains. The BIOS doesn't know or care about partition types, but some BIOS boot loaders can handle only primary partitions. The GRUB boot loader used by Ubuntu is *not* one of the fussy ones, though; it can load Linux from either primary or logical partitions.

Comment: I think I may be asking the wrong question. It was GRUB that wasn't recognized from using BIOS to launch to '/stb' when I had installed a Logical Partition. Having re-installed with a primary partition fixed this, however it may have nothing to do with the partition type?

Answer (score 0):

While your Windows resides on `sta` and its partitions, it is perfectly fine to install Ubuntu on a `stb` partition and choose to install bootloader (which is GRUB by default) on `stb`. Ubuntu will otomatically find your Windows installation and add it to the bootloader menu. After this, go to your BIOS and choose the entry that corresponds to `stb` as the first boot option.

When you boot your computer, you should first get the GRUB screen and be able to choose either Ubuntu or Windows.

Comment: I'm fairly sure this is exactly what I have done. I specified the 'stb' drive as the bootloader instillation location, however launching the 'stb' drive from BIOS yields a "No Operating System Found" message, so I can't progress.